How to use ADC to measure chained battery?
I have developed an ADC board using AD7192 to measure battery voltage. Assume each battery is 3V, the chained battery in series would gives 15V in total. Let the battery be BAT1+, BAT1-, BAT2+, BAT2- ... BAT5+ and BAT5-.
I have tested that when each battery disconnected (not in series), my ADC could read the correct voltage. If they are chained in series, my ADC gives strange values for each channel (for example, BAT2+ and BAT2- gives incorrect ADC values).
The problem is likely come from the ADC, my ADC reference voltage is 5V. For example, For BAT5+ and 5-, their potential differences is 15V-12V=3V. I have used DMM to check the ADC input, it's around 3V, but my ADC doesn't give the same correct values (in the case of series). How does the other battery affect my ADC reading?
I think some simple circuit need to be added before feeding the battery voltage to the ADC. For example, do I need to isolate them? Or the problem is from my Vref (since the chained battery would give higher voltage, like 12V, 15V, which exceed the Vref).

Are the AINCOM and REFIN– pins connected to ground?

Yes, both pins are connected to GND. I have tried both differential inputs and pseudo differential inputs. Both methods work with excellent accuracy . However, the problem arises when I connect the battery in series.


my ADC reference voltage is 5V

So REFIN+ and probably AVDD pins are connected to 5V.

However, the problem arises when I connect the battery in series.

The ADC and the rest of the system share the same ground (reference point) i.e. REFIN– = AINCOM = 0V. All of the channel measurements will be taken with respective to this node therefore all channel voltages must be within 0V - REFIN+ range.
Let's see what happens when the batteries are connected in series:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The V1 voltage is 3V with respect to common ground, and V2 is 6V, and V3 is 9V and so on.
Let's assume you try to measure the voltage across BAT2. Positive terminal is connected to AIN1, and negative terminal is connected to AIN2. Because AINCOM is connected to the ground, AIN1 voltage will be 6V and AIN2 voltage will be 3V, both with respective to the common ground. Although the differential voltage is 3V, the AIN1 voltage exceeds the REFIN+ voltage, hence the strange measurements you get.
Regardless of taking single-ended or differential measurement, the channel voltages must not exceed the ref voltage.

I have used DMM to check the ADC input, it's around 3V, but my ADC doesn't give the same correct values (in the case of series).

That's because the DMM is an isolated device and when you connect it across one of the batteries its reference (ground) point will be the node that the black probe is connected to.

I think some simple circuit need to be added

What you can do is use a differential amplifier then feed its output to one of the channels and take a single-ended measurement. Or, you can use voltage dividers to bring the node voltages within 0 - AVDD range but that will discharge the batteries so be careful with the selection of the divider resistors.
PS: There is a risk of having the ADC broken or damaged because of exceeding channel voltages.

The explanation of differential voltage and the excess of reference voltage cleared my doubts. Appreciate it! I would use the differential amplifier method with two additional multiplexer to select different battery channel (for feeding input to the diff. amp.).
